# Odin fails when trying to apply firmware

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, ota-update, device-firmware, odin

I'm trying to apply the correct firmware for my region UK and carrier which is EE but i can't seem to do this since it keeps failing on me when i start the process. This is the output from the logs.

```
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Binary Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/005> Removed!!
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<ID:0/005> Odin engine v(ID:3.1100)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/005> Initialzation..
<ID:0/005> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/005> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/005> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/005> sbl1.mbn
<ID:0/005> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/005> FAIL! (Auth)
<ID:0/005> 
<ID:0/005> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Just some background info as to why and what i've done previously.

The problem is i can't update the software since it keeps on saying processing failed. After looking into this it may be linked to region of the device since the baseband versionis I9505XXUGNK4 and the CSC part is not a UK code which is why i'm guessing the phone can't be updated.

Also i used kingoroot to root the device and i have a superuser app install as well before using Odin but surely this can't be an issue can it?